# Migrate resource files to Androidx

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-resources, androidx

I am doing refactoring --> migrate to Androidx in an Android Studio project.
I am noticing that only java files are been migrated, but not the xml resources.

It exists one method to automatically migrate them too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but one can right-click `res` directory, then "search" -> "replace in path"

in order to replace all the open/close tags, according to the migration guide.

Comment: I am doing but it's boring :D

Comment: Once having replaced the libraries, it is at least obvious what needs name-space correction.

Comment: i'm actually really surprised the migration doesn't cover xml files :/